# Is Oracle 11g database supported in windows 10?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, installation

When I tried to install oracle 11g on Windows 10 Home. I got the below error after the wizard started the installation:
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel.

I tried in another PC also windows 10 but the installation failed with the same error.

Comment: Are you running the install with local machine admin privileges?

Comment: It is not officially supported. You could install virtual box for example and some supported OS in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 is not certified officially.

[image]

Home edition Windows versions are not supported at all. That information you can find in the installation guide:

[Windows x64 Software Requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47798/reqs.htm#BABIICFE)